# Вывод массива

Tags: массивы, php

Есть простой массив `$al_ext = array('bmp','png');`
Выводит

```
Array ( [0] => bmp [1] => png )
```

Есть такой массив `$al_ext2 = array($cat['type']); $cat['type']` берется из бд, расширения также перечислены через запятую, но почему-то выводится

```
Array ( [0] => jpg,bmp )
```

Что-то не пойму в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В переменной **$cat['type']** содержится строка. Выглядит она примерно так: **"jpg,bmp"** и вы кладете в массив именно эту строку.

Для того что вы хотите сделать можно использовать фунецию **explode**.

Например так:

```
$al_ext2 = explode(",", $cat['type']);
```

Comment: А в первом случае у меня разве не строка?

Comment: @vitagame, в первом случае у вас две строки разделенные запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Добавил еще форматы и получилось   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => jpg [1] => bmp [2] => gif [3] => jpeg [4] => png ) )

Да даже с двумя форматами так. А должно быть немного не так.

Comment: что-то не так. Код покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: $al_ext = array(explode(",", $cat['type']));